# UWP app access is denied error when trying to read storage file

Tags: c#, .net, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I have a Windows 10 Mobile, UWP app. In my local folder:

```
ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
```

I am storing a sqlite db and a text log file.

Later on, if I try to read or convert to byte array, any of those files, I am getting an access is denied 8007005 error. It is not the file since it is happening on any file I try. Below is the code. Please note that when I set a breakpoint, the issue is not happening when I get the storage folder or even the storage file, I get all of those just fine. It is actually happening when I try to read or convert the file to byte array.

```
private async Task<byte[]> getDbFileByteArray()
{
    StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var logFile = await folder.GetFileAsync(DataConnection.SqliteFilename);
    var buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(logFile);
    return buffer.ToArray();
}
```

So, this method call should return a byte array of my file. As I mentioned, getting the storage folder and GetFileAsync both work fine and I get my file everytime without exception. It is actually on the line:

```
FileIO.ReadBufferAsync
```

Where I get the access is denied exception.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Upon further testing, I have found that when I run the UWP app on my Windows 10 desktop, I do not have any errors or exceptions. So, this seems to be specific to Windows 10 Mobile. However, I would have thought that since this is supposed to be "Universal" that this stuff would not happen.

Comment: The code you've posted is right. I've tested your code with Lumia 640 and it works well. The problem must in some other place. Could you place share a [mcve] that can reproduce your issue?

Comment: Could the file still be open and you are getting a file access error because another task has the file open